# HTML email signature broken in Outlook on Mac - Works fine on Windows?

Tags: html, css, macos, outlook, html-email

I have created an email signature and its tested working perfectly on the following: Outlook for Windows 2019, Outlook for iOS, Gmail webapp, Outlook webapp.

For some reason when i add it to Outlook for Mac version 16.29 it breaks. I sent it from my mac to my iphone and it wasn't responsive at all.

Any ideas why its only like this from the mac and working everywhere else? How do i fix it.

I have all the media queries to make it responsive. I have coded in tables so it should look fine in Outlook.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,400,500,600,700,800,900" />

    <style type="text/css">
         /* Client-Specific styles */
         #outlook a         { padding:0; } /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
         body               { width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }

         /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
         .ExternalClass     { width:100%; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
         .ExternalClass,
         .ExternalClass p,
         .ExternalClass span,
         .ExternalClass font,
         .ExternalClass td,
         .ExternalClass div { line-height:100%; } /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.*/
         img                { outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
         a img              { border:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
         p                  { margin:0px 0px !important; }
         table              { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
         table td           { border-collapse:collapse; }

         /* iPad Styles */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
             a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:none;
                 color:#000000;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 cursor:default;
             }
             .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:default;
                 color:#000000 !important;
                 pointer-events:auto;
                 cursor:default;
             }
         }

         /* iPhone Styles */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
             a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:none;
                 color:#000000;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 cursor:default;
             }
             .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                 text-decoration:default;
                 color:#000000 !important; 
                 pointer-events:auto;
                 cursor:default;
             }
         }

         /* Responsive styles */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            td[class=wrapper] {
                padding-top:0 !important;
                padding-left:0 !important;
                padding-right:0 !important;
            }

            table[class=mobile-view], td[class=mobile-view], img[class=mobile-view] {
                width:320px !important; 
                height:auto !important;    
            }

            td[class=clump] {
                display:block !important;
                padding-left:0 !important;
                padding-right:0 !important;
                width:100% !important;
            }

            td[class=aligncenter] {
                width:300px !important; 
                height:auto !important;
                text-align:center !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="540" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-view" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background;">
                <table width="540" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-view" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="left" class="clump">
                                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v1NoHym.jpg" alt="Avatar" border="0" height="200" width="200" style="display:block; outline:none; border:0;" />
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" align="left" class="clump" style="padding:0 0 0 0;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding:15px 0 0 20px;">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; font-size:22px; line-height:30px; font-weight:800; color:#2f3542;">First Name</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; font-size:15px; line-height:22px; font-weight:500; color:#989faf;">Position</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                                <td style="padding:20px 0 0 15px;">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width="40%" class="clump">
                                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td width="28" height="30" valign="top"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qdSJcZJ.png" alt="Web" border="0" height="22" width="22" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></td>
                                                                                <td align="left" width="" height="30" valign="top"  style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:600; color:#2f3542;"><a href="tel:0800 246 1809" style="text-decoration:none; color:#2f3542;">0000 0000 000</a></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding:5px 0 0 15px;">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>              
                                                            <td width="60%" class="clump">
                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td width="28" height="30" valign="top"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mDkpstX.png" alt="Email" border="0" height="22" width="22" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></td>
                                                                            <td width="" height="30" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:600; color:#2f3542;"><a href="mailto:info@example.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#2f3542;">info@example.com</a></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding:5px 0 9px 15px;">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="40%" class="clump">
                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td width="28" height="30" valign="top"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qdSJcZJ.png" alt="Web" border="0" height="22" width="22" style="display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></td>
                                                                            <td width="" height="30" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; font-size:12px; line-height:24px; font-weight:600; color:#2f3542;"><a href="https://example.com/" style="text-decoration:none; color:#2f3542;">example.com</a></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="" align="left" style="background; padding:0 0 0 40px;">
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/e1Ykoqm.png" alt="Facebook" height="35" width="35" border="0" style="padding:0 0 3px 0; display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSFaFlh.png" alt="Twitter" height="35" width="35" border="0" style="padding:0 0 3px 0; display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/SAtoqFt.png" alt="Instagram" height="35" width="35" border="0" style="padding:0 0 3px 0; display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/L9Z3ciV.png" alt="LinkedIN" height="35" width="35" border="0" style="padding:0 0 3px 0; display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jE3sFh0.png" alt="YouTube" height="35" width="35" border="0" style="padding:0 0 3px 0; display:block; border:0; outline:none;" /></a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table width="540" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-view" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="background;">
                    <table width="540" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-view" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" align="left" class="clump" style="padding:20px 0 0 20px;">
                                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tGGrM3B.jpg" alt="Avatar" border="0" height="120" width="120" style="display:block; outline:none; border:0;" />
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" align="left" class="clump" style="padding:0 0 0 0;">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding:15px 0 0 20px;">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; font-size:11px; line-height:22px; font-weight:500; color:#989faf;">This message and any attachments are confidential and intended for the named addressee(s) only. If you have received this message in error, please notify the sender then delete the message. Any unauthorized modification, use or dissemination is prohibited. The sender shall not be liable for this message if it has been modified, altered, falsified, infected by a virus or even edited or disseminated without authorization. </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure you have a viewport tag, like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that once i get home and update you.

Comment: Still the same issue. Its not a general responsive issue as it works fine everywhere else. Its specific to mac

Comment: Do you mind posting screenshots of your issue. I can't seem to replicate any non-responsive issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you could try.

1. You are missing the quotation marks in your css `td[class=wrapper]` should be `td[class="wrapper"]`
2. I have bad experience with using this kind of css selectors, try changing all to a normal .-format, like `td[class=wrapper]` is `td.wrapper`